# How do I check if the account is saved?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the program to search if the user has created an account or not.

```
print'\n'
search = raw_input("For which account are you searching: ")
f = shelve.open("passwords.dat")
passwrd = f[search]
entry = passwrd[0]
f.close()
for line in passwrd:
    if search in line:
        print line
        print '\n'
    print "I'm sorry we could not find any account related to " + search
    print'\n'
```

This is what I have tried and every time I run it with an account that hasn't been created, it gives me this error

```
File "E:\password.py", line 35, in find_account
    for line in f[search]:
  File "C:\Python24\lib\shelve.py", line 118, in __getitem__
    f = StringIO(self.dict[key])
  File "C:\Python24\lib\bsddb\__init__.py", line 219, in __getitem__
    return self.db[key]
KeyError: 'f'
```

How would I check it and I don't get an error, so my program doesn't end?

Comment: if key in self.db: ...

Comment: P.S.: The next time you ask a question please give us the code where the Error occurs.

Comment: That is the part of the code where the error occurs...

Comment: @palsch I tried `if key in self.db:` and I get this error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: where in the posted code is "for line in f[search]:"?

Comment: try "if search in f:" before "passwrd = f[search]"

Comment: Oh sorry that was the error code for when I changed `for line in passwrd` to `for line in f[search]` sorry didn't realize that I've tried a few things just didn't realize which error code I coppied

Comment: No, still putting out errors

Comment: let's discuss outside... SO is complaining ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93007/discussion-between-pal-sch-and-deliriousmistakes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you open it with `shelve` if "search" is in the dictionary it's saved as(f), if it is saved it does the `if` statement if it isn't it goes to else.

```
print '\n'
search = raw_input("For which account are you searching: ")
f = shelve.open("passwords.dat")
if search in f:
    account = f[search]
    print account
else:
    print "I'm sorry we could not find any account related to " + search
print '\n'
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You posted different code from what the error is reporting. I'm going to assume you just changed `for line in f[search]:` to `for line in passwrd:`. In that case you need to first check if you even have `search` available in your file. You can either put it first:

```
if search in f:
    for line in f[search]:
        ...
```

or give it an empty default:

```
for line in f.get(search, []):
    ...
```

Comment: It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.