# What is causing 'int' object has no attribute 'has_key'?

Tags: python

I have changed my code to:

```
print '\n'
search = raw_input("For which account are you searching: ")
f = shelve.open("passwords.dat")
for line in f:
    if search in f:
        passwrd = f[search]
        entry = passwrd[0]
        f.close()
        print line
        print '\n'
print "I'm sorry we could not find any account related to " + search
print '\n'
f.close()
```

And now it won't accept any correct accounts and gives off this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Why am I now getting this message?

```
  File "E:\password.py", line 98, in program_start
    find_account()
  File "E:\password.py", line 36, in find_account
    if search in f:
  File "C:\Python24\lib\shelve.py", line 107, in __contains__
    return self.dict.has_key(key)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Comment: Which line is line 98?

Comment: `f` is a file pointer. This line is wrong: `passwrd = f[search]`. Not sure what you are trying to do but you can't index "f" like that.

Comment: @RobertB  f is a https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html, not a file pointer

Comment: @RobertB This was the first way I wrote it and the correct accounts worked, but it would end the program if wrong anser now it only lets me input wrong answers. Heres the first try: [try1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268274/how-do-i-check-if-the-account-is-saved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shelve returns a single dict.
So it doesn't make sense to read multiple lines from it from what I can tell.

I think this should work:

```
print '\n'
search = raw_input("For which account are you searching: ")
with shelve.open("passwords.dat") as f:
    for passwords in f:
        if search in passwords:
            password = passwords[int(search)]
            entry = passwrd[0]
            print passwords
            print '\n'
        else:
            print "I'm sorry we could not find any account related to " + search
print '\n'
```

Comment: Seems like it's. But is put `f.close()` inside the `for` loop correct?

Comment: @RobertB After changing it I get this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\password.py", line 103, in ?
    program_start()
  File "E:\password.py", line 98, in program_start
    find_account()
  File "E:\password.py", line 37, in find_account
    passwrd = line[search]
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: No. Don't close `f` until you are done processing all the lines. So outside of the for loop. Otherwise, the program will attempt to loop again, attempt to read from a closed file, and throw another error

Comment: @RobertB Actually I recommend use `with` here. And about OP said that his problem, maybe `search = int(raw_input("For which account are you searching: "))` or `password = passwords[int(search)]`?

Comment: Read up on the `with` statement.

Comment: @RobertB I'm getting syntac error on shelve in `with shelve.open(...`

Comment: `if search in passwords:` is not correct because `passwords` is a `_io.TextIOWrapper`. You should read it like `for password in passwords` or `password = passwords.read()` before use it.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. The 3.5 shelve is much different than 2.7.

Comment: @RobertB No problem, I've just edited your answer, maybe this can work now.

Comment: I'm actually using 2.4.4 only because I need this version for class

Comment: And it works thank you so much it has been frustrating me for the past 4 gours

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Really? Python 2.4.4 was released on October 18, 2006. That's almost ten years ago. :P

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't for the class I wouldn't be using it. I have python 3.x on my desktop on a virtual machine, but im not at home :/